# fetch data from CoreData module

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on a project in Swift 3.0 and I have a `CoreData` module with five attributes with type String, and with the `NSManageObject` named `MP3Details`. They are namely, duration, `trackID`, `trackName`, `trackURL`.

The requirement is that once I pass a `trackID` I need to retrieve the elements related to that ID. For instance once I pass the `trackID` I should get the track duration, `trackName`, etc, belonging to that track ID.

As of now what I get is an empty array. The partially done code where I pass the `trackID` and get the information for the belongs to that ID as below. What am I missing here?

Method where I pass the `trackID`

```
if let arr = StorageManager.getTrackId(playlistName: playlistName) {
    for object in arr {
        let trackId = object.trackID
        print(trackId ?? "ID")

        if let detailsArr = StorageManager.getTrackDetails(trackId: trackId) {
           print("CoreDataItemArray :", detailsArr)

        }
    }
```

method whether I request the details from CoreData

```
public static func getTrackDetails(trackId:String?) -> [MP3Details]?{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: MP3_DETAILS_ENTITY)
    if(trackId != nil){
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"trackID = %@", trackId!)
    }
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do{
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        print("Result : ",results)
        if(results.count > 0 ){

            return results as? [MP3Details]
        }else{
            print("No Mp3 results for the track ID")
        }

    }catch{
        print("Error in fetching items")
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: No you can't access core data with above code swift 3.0. The accessing of  core data changed in swift. You can directly access core data persistentContainer.

Comment: an code snippet would much appreciate, cuz the thing is when I pass a nill value instead of the trackID i get the Mp3Details

Comment: Up to now I didn't work on swift. But I had the code for that.  wait i will check it.

Comment: I am adding the sample code below. Use that code and change the code as per your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

func loadData() -> Void {

```
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedObjContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")
    do {
        names = try managedObjContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error while fetching the data:: ",error.description)
    }

}

@IBAction func addNewName(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Name", message: "Add new name:", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { action in

        guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first ,
            let nameToSave = textField.text else{
                return
        }
        print("nameToSave::: ",nameToSave)
        self.save(name:nameToSave)
        self.hitListTableView.reloadData()
    }
    alert.addTextField()

    let alertCancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(alertAction)
    alert.addAction(alertCancelAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func save(name:String) -> Void {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: managedContext)
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        names.append(person)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error while saving the data: ",error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the predicate ? this doesn't satisfy my requirement

Comment: Sry yaar. In my mac I had the code. But in google drive code is missing.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the predicate line with:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"%K == %@", "trackID", trackId!)
```